# Use strings from ArrayList in regex

Tags: java, regex

I would like to know how can I check whether or not a string contains only values from ArrayList and maybe from outside the ArrayList too. Something like:

```
ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();
array.add("min");
array.add("max");
array.add("abs");
String plus = "+";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("?????"); // I'm asking what should I write here
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line); // line is the String I want to check
```

bla bla bla... (line is the String I want to check)

I mean, What should I write insted of the "?????" in order to check if the String line contains only the exact Strings from array and the string plus ("+") for example.

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Try `(min|max|abs|\\+)` Simply from a string from the array and use that pattern.

Comment: Why not just use `line.equals(array.get(i))` in a for loop? I don't see any need for regex based on the way you describe the problem. If you **need** to use regex for some reason, see comment #1.

Answer (score 0):

Read it, create a string from it

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for(String str : array) {
  builder.append(str).append("|");
}
builder.setLength(builder.length() - 1);
```

then

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(" + builder.toString() + "|\\+)");
```

p.s i used @Braj patten, i don't know if right.

Comment: you missed one thing that is ^ and $ for exact match.

Comment: If I remember correctly you aren't required to supply `^` and `$` for `Pattern`

Answer (score 0):

> check if the String line contains only the *exact* Strings from array and the string plus ("+")

Simply form a regex from the array. It will be in this form `^(min|max|abs)\+$`.

Here `^` represents beginning of a line and `$` represents ending of the line for *exact match*.

Read about more pattern here [Java Regex Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Answer (score 0):

if I am not wrong then you might me looking for below code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();
    array.add("min");
    array.add("max");
    array.add("abs");
    String line = "Max";
    Pattern pattern = null;
    boolean status = false;
    String plus = "+";
    for (String s : array) {
        pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b" + s + "\\b" + "[" + plus + "]",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            status = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (status) {
        System.out.println("match");
    } else {
        System.out.println("not match");
    }
}
```